# How to change the position of close/minimize/maximize buttons from top right to top left?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, gnome-shell, window-buttons

Is it possible to change thee position of the close/minimize/maximize windows buttons from the default top right, as it is in Windows, to the more Mac style of having it to the left?

Comment: install a gtk theme with that look, such as [White Sur](https://github.com/vinceliuice/WhiteSur-gtk-theme)

Answer (score 1):

Install Tweaks from Ubuntu Software or using a terminal with the command:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

After installation, open Tweaks and navigate to *Window Titlebars* and select *Placement* by clicking on *Left*.

Change to either side at will.

[image: Tweaks Window Titlebars menu]